# Textures quality poor when zoomed out

Tags: ios, opengl-es

Im porting my app to iOS, and while it has the same gl calls regarding texture binding, the quality gets very poor when zoomed out (mipmaps are enabled). Is there something wrong with this texture loading code?

EDIT: Im starting to think this is actually a retina display issue.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"jpg"];
    NSData *texData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:texData];

if (image == nil)
    NSLog(@"Do real error checking here");

GLuint width = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage);
GLuint height = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
void *imageData = malloc( height * width * 4 );
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate( imageData, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big );

// Flip the Y-axis
CGContextTranslateCTM (context, 0, height);
CGContextScaleCTM (context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
CGContextClearRect( context, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ) );
CGContextDrawImage( context, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ), image.CGImage );

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);

CGContextRelease(context);

free(imageData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a retina display issue. After some googling i came to this article which explains that the default scaleFactor is 1, which is why the textures looked bad on my device.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreens/SupportingHiResScreens.html